# How to add event listener for an object that i assigned a value from another class in Lua?

Tags: class, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener

I am trying to write a touch event for the object that i assigned the value of another class' function value into. However, it gives me this error: attempt to call 'addEventListener' nil value.

Here is my fish.lua code:

```
function class()
 local cls = {}
 cls.__index = cls
 return setmetatable(cls, {__call = function (c, ...)
    instance = setmetatable({}, cls)
    if cls.__init then
        cls.__init(instance, ...)
    end
    return instance
  end})
end


Color= class()

function Color:__init(image)
  self.image=display.newImage(image,30,30)
end

originalImage="fish.small.red.png"
differentImage="fish.small.blue.png"
```

And here is my main.lua code:

```
require  "fish"

local fishImage=Color(originalImage)

function listen(event)
if(phase.event=="began") then
    fishImage=Color(differentImage)
  end
 end

fishImage: addEventListener("touch", listen)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fishImage` is an instance of a class you created (Color) which doesn't have a method named `addEventListener`, at least not in the code you've shown. Perhaps you meant:

```
fishImage.image:addEventListener('touch', listen)
```

Which is adding an event listener to the corona image object your Color class encapsulates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lots of bugs. But use this as an example:
fish.lua

```
local fish = {}

fish.color = function(image)
    local image = display.newImage(image,30,30)
    return image
end

return fish
```

main.lua

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local fish = require("fish")
local fishImage = fish.color("Icon.png")

local function listen(event)
    if(event.phase=="began") then
        fishImage=fish.color("Icon-60.png")
    end
end

fishImage:addEventListener("touch", listen)
```